# How to scale down an astroid

Tags: java, graphics

I'm working on a assignment to generate 2 astroids (Not Asteroids) on a 400x400 Display Panel. Via a method called "drawAstroids", I was able to make the first one, but I'm having some trouble making the 2nd one. Instead of making the following:
[2 astroids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6zqJ.png)
This is what's happening: 
[1 astroid and one yuck!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhwMl.png)

I thought I could just change the scale an size settings with the second method, but I can't seem to make the 2nd one look like a smaller version of the 1st one. This is my code so far. Any tips as to how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GraphicsProject
{

    //main method
   public static void main (String[]args){
    //Initialize the variable
    //The Window is 400 x 400 pixels in size
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel (400,400);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    drawAstroid1(g,0,0,400);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    drawAstroid2(g,0,0,200);
    }

   public static void drawAstroid1(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size){ 
       int scale = size/40; 

       for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++ ){
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, y + scale * i, size/2 + scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, y + scale * i, 200 - scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, size - scale * i, 200 - scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, size - scale * i, size/2 + scale * i, size/2);

        }
    }
   public static void drawAstroid2(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size){ 
       int scale = size/40; 

       for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++ ){
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, y + scale * i, size/2 + scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, y + scale * i, 200 - scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, size - scale * i, 200 - scale * i, size/2);
           g.drawLine(x + size/2, size - scale * i, size/2 + scale * i, size/2);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem stems from the hardcoded value of 200. Your images are different sizes, and the x coordinate that represents the horizontal center of the image changes with size. If you replace the 200 with an expression that gives you the center x coordinate considering the size of the image, you should get a better result. You should also ask yourself why you are passing in x and y values to your two methods, and what you are doing with them -- in particular why the x and y are only added to the first coordinate in each line.

Comment: You're right. I've changed the hardcoded 200 into size/2 and it worked properly afterwards. Thank you.